# Prompt user with custom dialog box trying to navigate with unsaved data

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

When user clicks on other link to navigate without saving all edited data a prompt should be given.

Implemented using window.onbeforeunload its working as expected, but I want it to be customized prompt rather than browser default prompt.

Can anyone tell how to implement.

Comment: why don't you create a custom popover using HTML elements and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create some html elements (to be displayed as prompt box), will have to style them and eventually code it to confirm from user on window.onbeforeunload

An example can be found here

http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1386

Answer (score 0):

You have a variety of prompts elements customized using `jquery` . I found the below one most useful. Have look at [Alertify plugin](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/)

Prompt window can be easily configured as below after adding the required css and js files to your project ,

```
// confirm dialog
alertify.confirm("Message", function (e) {
    if (e) {
        // user clicked "ok"
    } else {
        // user clicked "cancel"
    }
});
```